# Why is my docker container not `apt-get update` - 404s

Tags: docker, debian

I'm using the php:5.5.38-apache docker image.

When I remote into it, and run `apt-get update` it seems unable to access repos:

```
# apt-get update
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates Release
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found       

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What's up with it? Network access seems fine:

```
# ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.187.206): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.250.187.206: icmp_seq=0 ttl=37 time=58.393 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.187.206: icmp_seq=1 ttl=37 time=22.499 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.187.206: icmp_seq=2 ttl=37 time=21.658 ms
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why:

> I'm using the php:5.5.38-apache docker image.

---

PHP 5.5 is **ancient**. It reached [end of life](https://www.php.net/eol.php) on  21 Jul 2016.

It is so old that the docker image uses a version of Debian ([Jessie](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/)) that is also unsupported:

> Jessie also had benefited from Long Term Support (LTS) until the end of June 2020.

---

You're getting 404 errors because that version of Debian has had its packages deleted from the apt repository.

---

The oldest version of PHP that gets any [support](https://www.php.net/supported-versions) is 8.0 but even that is for security fixes only.

You should upgrade to PHP 8.2 which is the current version of PHP.

If this is an existing project, then this will probably be a significant amount of work because you've been neglecting necessary maintenance (i.e. making incremental upgrades) for the last decade.

Comment: Yeh it's an old app that needs a dev environment but will look at other options, thanks